# Show that $f$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization

Given an endomorphism $f$ of a vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $n$ such that $f(f(x))=3f(x)-2x$.

Let $E_1=\ker(f-Id)$ and $E_2=\ker(f-2Id)$. Show that:

1. $E_1$ and $E_2$ form a direct sum.
2. $E=E_1 \oplus E_2$. Is $f$ diagonalizable?

Comment: Are you sure the equation shouldn't be $f(f(x))={\color{red} 3}f(x)-2x$?

Comment: Why should that be the equation, @SpamIAm ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Because the subspaces $E_1$ and $E_2$ are eigenspaces for $\lambda = 1, 2$.  Currently the minimal polynomial divides $t^2 - 2t + 2$, so neither of these is an eigenvalue.  With the $3$, it would be $t^2 - 3t + 2 = (t - 1)(t - 2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints for you to understand/justify/work out:

$$x\in\ker(f-Id.)\cap\ker(f-2Id.)\implies\begin{cases}f(x)=x\\{}\\f(x)=2x\end{cases}\implies x=0 $$

$$f^2=3f-2I\implies x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)\;\text{is the minimal polynomial of}\;\;f\;\text{ (why?)}$$

and thus $\;f\;$ is diagonalizable

Comment: I think you've made an arithmetic mistake.  The minimal polynomial currently divides $x^2 - 2x + 2$, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: If it is not the minimum polynomial then it would be either $(x-2)$ or $(x+1)$ which is a contradiction. Now since the minimal polynomial factors into first degree parts, f is diagonalizable. Right? By the way i don't think that just from here we can deduce that $E$ is the exact direct sum of $E_1$ and $E_2$ or did i miss something?

Comment: First, SpamIam is right: I ommited a $\;2\;$ in that polynomial, so it must be $\;x^2-2x+2\;$ which is irreducible over the reals. Yet, with Marko's correction it *actually* is $\;x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)\;$ , and since it is a product of **different** linear factors (and minimal in fdegree...why??), that *must be* the minimal pol. of the endomorphism and thus it is diagonalizable. I shall edit now.